# ¿Como establecer varias configuraciones para pantallas de distintos tamaños?

Tags: android

Mi apk funciona de maravilla en mi telefono que tiene una resolucion de 2k y una pantalla de 5.5 pulgadas. Al probarla en un telefono 320x480 de resolucion solo se ve una parte donde muestro fotos los botones no se ven. Hay alguna forma de configurar el espacio de las actividades acorde el tamaño de la pantalla? Gracias por la ayuda.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="420dp" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButtonLogin"
    android:layout_width="105dp"
    android:layout_height="105dp"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_below="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/boton_directorio"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_login" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButtonDirTele"
    android:layout_width="105dp"
    android:layout_height="105dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imageButtonLogin"
    android:background="@drawable/boton_directorio"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_dir_tel" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButtonCorreo"
    android:layout_width="105dp"
    android:layout_height="105dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageButtonDirTele"
    android:background="@drawable/boton_correo"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_correo"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Como logro que esto sea diferente en dispositivos diferentes?

Comment: Disculpa, soy medio novato en esto, recien estoy entrando al mundo de la programacion. No podes usar medias query o algo por el estilo?
Por ejemplo cuando hacemos una web usamos media query en el CSS. La pantalla al ser x tamaño hace tal cosa, si pasa ese tamaño hace otra y asi

Comment: android studio cuenta con algo que no me se el nombre es como parametros cuando creas un layout que los probe y no me funcionan por ejemplo para tablets pones size en x large o large pero cuando se trata small solo es para relojes inteligentes, me entiendes?

Comment: Perdon, la verdad que ni idea de Android studio, recien estoy empezando con java, html, css y base de datos todo muy basico. Entiendo lo que me decis pero no se darte una respuesta sobre eso

Comment: tranquilo no es que yo sepa mucho tampoco

Comment: Muestra el xml de tu aplicación.

Comment: ya lo mostre @DavidMinaya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto sucede por que estas asignando un ancho y un alto estático a todos los elementos de tu vista `android:layout_width=""` y `android:layout_height=""` lo cual hace que al correr tu app en un teléfono con dimensiones diferentes a las que lo diseñaste en un inicio la forma de ver tus elementos sea totalmente diferente.

Lo que puedo ver en tu archivo XML es que quieres poner un tres `ImageButton` bajo un `ViewPager` para lo que te recomiendo poner el siguiente código:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:background="@color/color"
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonLogin"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="105dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonDirTele"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="105dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonCorreo"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="105dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

De esta manera se verá con las mismas proporciones en cualquier teléfono o tablet. Para mayor información revisa pagina
[compatibilidad con diferentes tamaños de pantalla](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes) que muestra a detalle más información.

Comment: muchas gracias de verdad

Comment: Un gusto poder ayudarte